# Ember fast boot for a single route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

Is there a way I can do a fastboot just for a single route for an Ember app?

Looking at current ember-cli fastboot repo in github, they solve the problem about having two instances of Ember running by disabling the autoboot in an initializer and probably having the issue of saving ember application state.

We are currently working on rails with and old version of ember.

Not sure if using phantom js for getting a snapshot of that view, would be a great solution.

Looking forward for a temporary faster solution, any suggestions?